# Unity 2018 can't find android sdk path on mac osx

Tags: unity, android

I use osx catalina 10.15.5 and run couple version of unity 2019 without problem. but when i download unity 2018 (2018.4.24f1), it couldn't find android sdk.

the default location for the sdk is :

> /Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/**[unity
> version]**/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/SDK

for example, unity 2019.4.24f1, the default location for the sdk is here :

> /Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.24f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/SDK

and everything is working fine.

But for 2018 version, the android build support already install for this version, but there's no SDK folder :

> /Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2018.4.24f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/
> ... **NO SDK FOLDER HERE**

Does anyone can help to fix it ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you set the path for it in the editor?

Comment: The 2019 path was set automatically when i install unity (with android build support selected). But when i install 2018, the sdk was not created.